# pygame and QlineEdit boxes error

Tags: python, pygame, qlineedit

I have found a game: memory.py [here](http://joel-murielle.perso.sfr.fr/) (scroll down) or the [direct link](http://joel-murielle.perso.sfr.fr/memory.py) or a [snapshot](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://joel-murielle.perso.sfr.fr/memory.py).

and I'm modifying it. The first thing I'm trying to do is to set the wait time from a QlineEdit box.

I have changed this:

```
pygame.time.wait(500)
```

to this:

```
pygame.time.wait(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
```

and got his error:

```
pygame.time.wait(self.ui.lineEdit.text()) typeError: delay requires one integer argument
```

then I used:

```
pygame.time.wait(int(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))
```

and got his error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I don't know what to do, anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't convert the empty string `''` into an integer. How long should pygame wait if the edit box is empty?

Answer (score 0):

The text box is returning an empty string. You should check if the string is empty first.

```
text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
if text:
    time= 0 #or some default value if no time is specified
else
    time = int(text)
pygame.time.wait(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

@salva Nicolas is right.

The best way to check is check the condition if a text is entered. Although this has a problem.

If you just enter a space in the line edit, you will get an error. It is still not a fool proof method.

to check if a valid text has been entered in to the QLineEdit you need to use validator.

or

You can try converting the qlineedit in to integer or float using try and if it throws an exception you can do something else.

```
try:
    x_min=ast.literal_eval(str(self.ui.x_min_3d.text())) # Try to convert
except:
    x_min=0 # else do something else
```